# My asp.net core web api doesn't update on MySQL workbench

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I was able to link my asp.net core web API to MySQL database and all but when I make a post request, it does not update on the database and so on.

Comment: welcome to SO. how is your api suposed to update your database? 
How do you connect your api and your database?

Comment: @Isparia
 "Default" : "server=localhost;user=root;database=personsdata;password=****;port=3306"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

And on my program.cs, I have

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
  options.UseMySql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"), new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 29))));

These are my appsettings.js an program.cs files

Comment: ok it would be better and easier to read if you would put this in your question directly, also please show us you r api call which is supossed to save something ^^, the action is fine ^^

Comment: Are you sure the web api has connected to mysql successfully? How do you write sql from your web api to mysql?